# Join two MySQL queries and result in the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner to coding. Is it possible to join two queries into one? I have googled but I didn't get what exactly I am looking for. My first query is:

```
SELECT filename
     , course.cname
     , DATE_FORMAT(pd_course_file.creationDate,"%D %M %Y") as date
     , type 
  FROM pd_course_file
  JOIN course 
    ON pd_course_file.course_id = course.id
```

Now whatever the result of type column for example the result of type I got pdf then my next query will be

```
Select icons from fileType  where type = 'pdf'
```

How can I join both queries?

Comment: You can call any query a subquery and join it to another.  How would you join the icons query to your first query?  is there a common ID?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Don't think about "queries".  Think about *results*.

Comment: @Twelfth Yes the result of type in the first query will in where clause of 2nd query

Comment: scaisEdge's first query looks right then and I'll defer to his answer (remove the ft.type-'pdf' at the end of it) and you can include filetype.icon in your select list.   Join to filetype on course.type = filetype.type...er, unless type is in  pd_course_file, then join to that instead ;)

Comment: @Twelfth Can you please rewrite it.

Comment: You want me to rewrite scaisEdge's entire query without the last 17 chars of "and ft.type='pdf'" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the type is the file type you could use a join

```
SELECT filename
  , course.cname
  ,DATE_FORMAT(pd_course_file.creationDate,"%D %M %Y") as date
  , type 
  , ft.icon 
FROM pd_course_file p
INNER JOIN course ON pd_course_file.course_id = course.id 
INNER JOIN fileType ft ON ft.type = pd_course_file.type  and ft.type='pdf'
```

oterwise if ever is a pdf but you have not a  relatio you could use a cross join

```
SELECT filename
  , course.cname
  ,DATE_FORMAT(pd_course_file.creationDate,"%D %M %Y") as date
  , type 
  , ft.icon 
FROM pd_course_file p
INNER JOIN course ON pd_course_file.course_id = course.id 
CROSS JOIN fileType ft
where ft.type = 'pdf'
```

Comment: I said pdf as example in my first query whatever I will get the result of type in first query that will be in where clause of 2nd query

Comment: Thank You, I got what I am looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: suggestion: you can make your query more readable by writing:
JOIN Course  USING (course_id)

instead of
INNER JOIN course ON pd_course_file.course_id = course.id

Answer (score -1):

You could add a subquery as part of the select.  Like so...

```
SELECT filename
     , course.cname
     , DATE_FORMAT(pd_course_file.creationDate,"%D %M %Y") as date
     , type
     , (select icons from filetype where type = 'PDF') as icons
  FROM pd_course_file
  JOIN course 
    ON pd_course_file.course_id = course.id
```

But that will get you a list of all the icons from the fileType table in put them in the icons column.  If there's something else to key off of in the fileType table, you'd want to add that to the selecting subquery.  For example:

```
SELECT filename
     , course.cname
     , DATE_FORMAT(pd_course_file.creationDate,"%D %M %Y") as date
     , type
     , (select icon from filetype ft where ft.type = 'PDF' and ft.file_course_id = pd_course_file.course_id) as icon
  FROM pd_course_file
  JOIN course 
    ON pd_course_file.course_id = course.id
```